# How do I log in firebase analytics predefined events in react native?

Tags: react-native, google-analytics

I have a React native app and I followed the instructions on this [page](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage) and I managed to log in to a custom event as suggested:

```
analytics().logEvent("some_event", {
          uid: user.id,
          param: someParam,
        });
```

This works fine, and I am able to see it on my analytics. However, I have a problem when I try t use predefined events. As far as I understand the list of predefined events is [here](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage#reserved-events): I tried to use `login` event, which is detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?sjid=5412214739169921776-EU&client_type=gtag#login)  So in my app, after a user logs in successfully, I call:

```
await analytics().logLogin({
          method: 'email',
        });
```

No error is thrown, however, I don't see any logs in my firebase analytics for the login event. I do see however logs for my previous custom event.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?